# How to circumvent missing .stop() implementation of RTCRtpTransceiver in Chrome / Chromium

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc

I currently try to build a webrtc application that uses the RTCRtpTransceiver-Objects of the WebRTC standard. I add video and audio tracks to the connection and then, some time later, I try to remove them.
I do this with the following lines:

```
// part of a method, that searches the transceiver to stop and assigned it to the 'transceiver' variable
peerconnection.removeTrack(transceiver.sender);
if (transceiver.direction === "sendrecv") transceiver.direction = "recvonly";
else transceiver.direction = "inactive";
```

I know that this will set the remote track just to muted state and is like replacing the transceivers sender track with null, but Chrome has not implemented `direction="stopped"` or `transceiver.stop()` yet, [see Issue 980879](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=980879).
So what to do instead?
The remote peer just sees the current direction of the receiver becoming inactive and the receiver track gets muted.
Ergo, it does not remove the track for the remote peer in my application and muted tracks accumulate over time and even worse for video tracks: they get displayed like normal muted tracks.
 
I also cannot remove every muted track, since my application is required to allow muted and unmuted tracks (- muted by the user, not muted due to being stopped). 
Muting tracks by entirely removing them will lead to another offer-answer exchange and this takes some time. I would prefer to just mute by replacing the track with null (without having to send sdp back and forth), as the WebRTC standard seems to allow and Chrome already implements.
The next option would be correlating the transceivers on both ends and sending a message from the stopping peer to the remote one to make the remote one stop the received track. This may be possible (I believe the transceivers mid should be the same, according to the spec), but in my opinion it is also an ugly way.
What i cannot do is just sending over the media track id, since this one is different for the stopping peer and the remote peer, so I cannot just send a message like *'please stop your track with id xyz'* (it would make things easy, but well, it just doesn't work like this).
So, now I have the following questions:

1. What is the current 'standard' way in which you and other webrtc developers solve this, as long stopping transceivers will not work in every browser? (chrome fixing it for current versions will probably take some time but being the most used browser, we cannot just ignore it)
2. Did someone somehow (by abusing DTFM, using magic or whatever...) bodged a polyfill together? (I believe Adapter.js hasn't made this somehow possible)
3. Is there another way besides muting=removing and sending remote-track-stop messages over the signaler? If not, what is the better option?

Answer (score 2):

What I ended up doing is choosing the signaling-solution.
I basically do

```
// part of a method, that searches the transceiver to stop and assigned it to the 'transceiver' variable
peerconnection.removeTrack(transceiver.sender);
if (transceiver.direction === "sendrecv") transceiver.direction = "recvonly";
else transceiver.direction = "inactive";
signaler.send({type: 'transceiver:stop', data: transceiver.mid});
```

And on the other side

```
// received sent message and called this method with message.data
onTransceiverStopMessage(mid){
   const transceiverToStop = peerconnection.getTransceivers().filter(transceiver => transceiver.mid === mid);
   transceiverToStop.receiver.track.stop()
   transceiverToStop.receiver.track.dispatchEvent(new Event('ended'));
}
```

The `dispatchEvent`-Call is necessary, since calling `stop` on a track does not trigger the `ended`-Event. 
It works well for my purpose, but I am still waiting for a solution to the piling up inactive transceivers (since they still impact performance, as the chrome issue states)

Comment: Did this `receiver.track.stop()` work for you on Chrome browser on android ?

Comment: I have to disappoint you, I haven't tested the mobile browsers and I am not up to date on the development regarding this - I only know that the chromium issue 980879 (stopping and stopped transceivers) is currently being worked on, so with a bit of luck, this temporary fix will become unnecessary with the next or next but one chrome version (I hope)

Comment: I updated the chrome browser to latest version. It is fixed there now. Thanks

Comment: @nasskalte.juni, Did you put this whole code in one function? What is signaler and where did you put onTransceiverStopMessage()? I am just getting confused about how to use it? Please explain.

Comment: @JaynaTanawala The context of the given (more or less pseudo- or snippet-) code is a project, in which I tried to use the [Perfect Negotiation Pattern](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#perfect-negotiation-example) to control how my WebRTC connection reacts to glare. I created a wrapper class, that wraps the RTCPeerConnection and just exposes methods to add, remove, mute MediaStreams. This class also contained the signaler, the out-of-band-transmission of messages to build up, control and tear down the connection (implemented via websockets). Other people might name this io or just socket.

Comment: @JaynaTanawala the upper snippet of code is called on the "remove"-method of the wrapper-class. It sets the transceiver direction in a way representing that there is no more outgoing media and then uses the signaler (our websocket-connection between the peers) to tell the other peer 'stop the track of the transceiver with that mid'. The lower code snippet is basically called when the websocket of the other peer receives that message. I didn't call it "socket" since I also wrote a signaler that communicated via [SSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) and AJAX-calls.

Comment: @nasskalte.juni, thank you so much for your answer. I just want to ask that Is it possible to directly close the connection between two peers?

Comment: @JaynaTanawala Just closing a connection? Sure, this should work. RtcPeerConnection.close() should be signaled _in-band_ (ergo over the underlying SRTP-Protocol, without sending anything over the websocket or whatever signaler) and will result in the other end receiving a signalingstatechange event, which you can catch with <peerconnection>.onsignalingstatechange = () => console.log(<peerconnection>.signalingState); // --> logs "closed".
If you just want that, you do not need something like transceivers, just listen for the event and remove any media you used